# integrate a Google Checkout payment system on a asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, google-checkout

I am planning to integrate a Google Checkout payment system on a asp.net website. The idea is that members can  fill up  details ( like  https://www.itechline.com/paymentgateway5/), but how.. i have no idea 
plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Was really tempted to do a [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) downvote on your question...but ok ~

If you spent a little time reading the [Google Checkout API documentation](https://developers.google.com/checkout/) you'll see that your intended goal, based *only* on the sample link you provided, **isn't** compatible with a *3rd party checkout service* like Google *Checkout*.

Your sample link requires that you:

- Work with a [payment processor/gateway service](http://www.google.com/search?q=payment+gateways)
- so that you can collect credit card information at your own web site
- and must comply with [PCI DSS requirements](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/merchants/)